# Preorder traversal of binary tree

Tags: c++, vector, binary-tree

Ques - Given the root of a binary tree, return the preorder traversal of its nodes' values.
[Link Here](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-preorder-traversal/)

I am solving this question by recursion approach . Given below is my code

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> preorderTraversal(TreeNode* root) {
        vector<int> ans;
        if(root)
        {
            ans.push_back( root -> val);
            preorderTraversal(root ->left);
            preorderTraversal(root ->right);
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

All the test cases are passed except one i.e **[1,null,2,3]**. But when I declare `vector<int> ans` before `vector<int> preorderTraversal(TreeNode* root)` the test case gives correct output. I want to know why this happens.

Comment: You need to get the return values from the recursive calls to `preorderTraversal` (i.e. the vectors) and add the elements in them to `ans`. Alternatively pass a `std::vector` by ref to `preorderTraversal` and fill it there.

Comment: You ignore return value of your preorderTraversal calls and these alter no external state so the question is meaningless.

Comment: The algorithm synopsis might be: (1) Insert `root->val` into `ans`. (2) Insert the entire result of `preorderTraversal(root->left)` into `ans`. (3) Insert the entire result of `preorderTraversal(root->right)` into `ans`. (4) return `ans`. You are doing (1) and (4). You are **not** doing (2) and (3). Example: `auto child{preorderTraversal(root->left)}; ans.insert(ans.end(), child.begin(), child.end());`.

Comment: Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions - local variables are specific to a function call, and if you don't store their return values they disappear.

Answer (score 2):

The `ans` variable is not shared among function calls, and you discard the result from the recursions, so you can add at most one element to the result.

Delegating to a helper function is a common solution that avoids copying and manual state management:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> preorderTraversal(TreeNode* root) {
        vector<int> ans;
        traverse(root, ans);
        return ans;
    }
private:
    void traverse(const TreeNode* root, vector<int>& ans) const
    {
        if(root)
        {
            ans.push_back(root->val);
            traverse(root->left, ans);
            traverse(root->right, ans);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`vector<int> ans;` is a local variable that is destroyed after call to `preorderTraversal`. Apart from that, you are ignoring return values of your recursive calls. I think you want to keep your `ans` as a class field and populate it with recursive calls:

```
class Solution {
public:
    void preorderTraversal(TreeNode* root) {
        if(root)
        {
            _ans.push_back( root -> val);
            preorderTraversal(root ->left);
            preorderTraversal(root ->right);
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<int> _ans;
};
```

Then of course you would need some accessors, a way to clear the results, etc. But I guess this is not the scope of your question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you ignore the return values from the recursive calls to `preorderTraversal`. Therefore your method will ever return maximum 1 value - the value of the `root` node.

A simple solution for your current code would be to store the result of the resursive call in a variable and append the elements to `ans`:

```
ans.push_back( root -> val);
auto l = preorderTraversal(root ->left);
ans.insert(ans.end(), l.begin(), l.end());
auto r = preorderTraversal(root ->right);
ans.insert(ans.end(), r.begin(), r.end());
```

This is not so efficient since the vectors from the recuresive calls are effectivly copied.

A more efficient approach would be to pass the result `vector` by reference to `preorderTraversal` (it should be created empty before calling it for the root). Then `preorderTraversal` can add elements (including recursivly) to this result `vector`.

An alternative for passing the result by reference is storing it in a member variable of the class, as shown in the other answer.